# How do I call a function that is a property value? (vue)

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a rich text editor package using another vue editor package (`<editor-menu-bar>` you see below is from the package, [TipTap](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap#editormenubar))

Its original button element looks like this.

```html
      <!--Editor.vue-->
      <editor-menu-bar :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
        <div class="menubar">

          <button
            class="menubar__button"
            :class="{ 'is-active': isActive.bold() }"
            @click="commands.bold" <!--commands.bold, commands.italic (...) are from the package-->
          >bold
          </button>

        </div>
      </editor-menu-bar>
```

I'm trying to make an interface where you can pass button data as props when the parent component uses the component above (Editor.vue). Then the buttons will be handled with `v-for`.

```
options = [
    { 
      style: 'bold',
      included: true
    },
    { 
      style: 'italic',
      included: true
    },
]
```

```html
      <editor-menu-bar :editor="editor" v-slot="{ commands, isActive }">
        <div class="menubar">

          <button
            v-for="option in this.options"
            v-bind:key="option"
            class="menubar__button"
            :class="{ 'is-active': isIncluded(option.style) }" <!--assume isIncluded was made-->
            @click="❓" <!--how can I refer to commands.bold, commands.italic... ?-->
          >
          </button>

        </div>
      </editor-menu-bar>
```

It's my first time to do anything with slot and I can't figure out how I can call the [scoped slot](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap#editormenubar) data `commands` to call package functions such as `commands.bold` or `commands.italic`.
The function names are generic so wish I could use syntax like this

```
@click="commands.{{option.style}}"
```

but of course it didn't work. You can find detailed interface of the editor [here](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap#extensions).

**final working version (edited)**

```html
          <button
            v-for="option in options"
            v-bind:key="option.style"
            class="menubar__button"
            :class="{ 'is-active': isActive[option.style]() }"
            @click="commands[option.style]()"
          >
          {{ option.style }}
          </button>
```

Comment: You cannot use the word "this" in the template it should be `option in options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
@click="commands[option.style]"
```

Comment: Thank you but can you point out a pitfall of using property accessor?
I double checked  that `option.style` is a string such as 'bold' or 'italic' but I get two erros.

`[Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.`

`[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error.`

Comment: That's another issue. Not coming from property accessor. Let me check again into your code and sort out.

Comment: The issue is coming from `v-bind:key="option"`

Comment: You may use `v-bind:key="option.style"` instead. Also note to the comment by Michael.

Comment: Ah  so `key` in the warning literally meant `:key`. After changing to `option.style` the errors are gone. Thank you.